# Como crear un diccionario dentro de un If

Tags: python

Decir si la palabra "python" aparece en el texto (uno a elección del usuario). Tips: usa bool para verificar si se encuentra, y **un diccionario para asociar el booleano con un string para mostrar al usuario**.

- Lo interpreto así:

  ```
    if "python" in texto:
      diccionario = {clave: valor}
      print (diccionario)
    else
    print ("La palabra python no se encuentra en el texto")
  ```
- No entiendo la parte de *"un diccionario para asociar el booleano con un string para mostrar al usuario".*

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

creo que deberias usar algo asi:
texto = input("Ingrese un texto: ")

```
if "python" in texto:
    diccionario = {True: "La palabra 'python' se encuentra en el texto."}
    print(diccionario[True])
else:
    diccionario = {False: "La palabra 'python' no se encuentra en el texto."}
    print(diccionario[False])
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, creo que va por ahí la resolución, a lo que apuntan mis profesores, voy a practicar resolverlo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La solución, de hecho, no utiliza ningún IF. Veamos la especificación:

> Decir si la palabra "python" aparece en el texto (uno a elección del usuario). Tips: usa bool para verificar si se encuentra, y un diccionario para asociar el booleano con un string para mostrar al usuario.

La voy a dividir en partes:

- > Decir si la palabra "python" aparece en el texto

  Esto en realidad es lo último que vamos a hacer, es el resultado final que verá el usuario. No lo podemos olvidar, pero no es por donde vamos a empezar.
- > en el texto (uno a elección del usuario)

  Ok, interpretemos esto como que el usuario tiene que introducir el texto, aunque no es del todo claro, también podría elegirlo de un menú o alguna serie de opciones predefinidas.
- > Tips: usa bool para verificar si se encuentra

  Acá, bueno, no hay muchas opciones. Si se encuentra o no es un dato booleano por naturaleza, pues solo puede tener valores True o False, digamos SI se encuentra o NO se encuentra.
- > un diccionario para asociar el booleano con un string para mostrar al usuario.

  Esta parte es vital y es por dónde vamos a comenzar a la hora de programar.

Con esta lista de requerimientos en mente, mi interpretación de cómo satisfacer los requerimientos (y algunos tips para que puedas convertirlo en código) va de esta manera:

- Crear un diccionario que asocie los valores booleanos con los mensajes que mostrarás al usuario. Por ejemplo:

  - `True` estaría asociado con `"La palabra python ha sido encontrada en el texto ingresado"`
  - `False` estaría asociado con `"No ha introducido la palabra python en el texto"`

  En resúmen el diccionario, una vez inicializado, contendrá los mensajes que se mostrarán al usuario cuando se encuentre o no la cadena `"python"` en el texto introducido.

  Recuerda que un diccionario es una estructura que asocia llaves con valores, la sintaxis para declararlo es:

  ```
    diccionario = {
      Llave1: Valor1,
      Llave2: Valor2
    }
  ```
- Pedir un texto al usuario y guárdalo en una variable. Para ello puedes valerte de la función `input()`, por ejemplo:

  ```
    texto = input("introduzca el texto a analizar: ")
  ```
- Ahora averiguaremos si esa variable contiene el texto `"python"`, pero el resultado de esa comparación no lo usaremos como condición en un `if`, sino que vamos a almacenarlo en una variable de tipo booleano.

  En otras palabras, necesitas encontrar una expresión que te indique si la palabra "python" está en el texto introducido por el usuario o no, pero en lugar de usar esta expresión en un if de esta manera

  ```
    if expresion:
  ```

  Vamos a dar una vuelta de tuerca y a recordar que la evaluación de *expresion* devuelve un valor booleano, y este valor bien puede almacenarse también en una variable usando el operador de asignación, es decir, lograríamos lo mismo que el if anterior así:

  ```
    variable = expresion
    if variable:
  ```

  Solo que en esta ocasión hemos almacenado el resultado de evaluar la expresión en una variable booleana.

  Hacemos esto es para poder **utilizar dicha variable como llave** en el diccionario que hemos preparado al inicio.

  Otra alternativa sería no almacenarlo en una variable sino utilizar directamente el resultado de la comparación, pero eso puede hacer el código más difícil de leer.
- Ahora, el paso final, imprimimos en pantalla el resultado de la búsqueda. Para imprimirlo, utilizaremos la variable booleana como *llave* para ubicar el texto correcto a imprimir dentro del diccionario que preparamos al inicio. Para ello podemos valernos de la función `print()` y recordar que obtenemos el valor asociado a una llave en un diccionario con la sintaxis: `diccionario[llave]`.

No te doy código directamente, porque creo que aún te toca hacer al menos esa parte de la tarea. Si te comento que, gran parte del trabajo del programador, es comprender los requerimientos y con ellos desarrollar un algoritmo (la secuencia de pasos que te acabo de dar).

Esa suele ser la parte más difícil de aprender. Una vez tienes clara la idea, escribir el código suele ser la parte más sencilla.

Comment: Buena respuesta c: El ejercicio es bastante malo en mi opinion: es poco claro y fuerza a usar un diccionario donde no tiene sentido usarlo. Parte de diseñar ejercicios es hacerlo bien. Y creo que hay mejor forma de introducir a los diccionarios.

Comment: No sé cuál sea el objetivo del _profesor_ en este caso, puede ser que su intención no sea tanto introducir a los diccionarios, como al hecho de que puede almacenarse el resultado de una expresión booleana, y que también se pueden utilizar valores booleanos como llaves o como índices.

Comment: Hola @DanteS. . Si que tiene sentido usar un diccionario (y mucho). Imagina que quieres hacer una aplicacion que funcione en varios idiomas. Lo que quieres es asociar el valor True con una frase, y no tener esa asociacion en el codigo. En estos casos lo comun es tener un archivo JSON con traducciones que lo cargas en un diccionario. Los diccionarios son muy muy utiles, no los subestimes.  Normalmente en una aplication no quieres tener "Hardcoded values" sino que quieres los valores en estructuras de datos.

Comment: Pero si es cuestion de traducción, no se usa true y false, si no que se usa una cadena de clave. Rara vez es util usar booleanos en diccionarios. Y sobre lo de jachguate es verdad, en ese sentido me equivoqué.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su colaboración y buena predisposición, muy agradecido de verdad, voy a poner en práctica lo que me explicaron.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que en la parte que no entiendes, solo tienes que crear el diccionario que asocie `True` a un texto y `False` a otro, para poder retornar el que corresponda (en mi ejemplo he puesto `1` y `0` en vez de `True` y `False`).

algo así:

```
diccionario = {0: 'Python no está en el texto', 1: 'Python si se encuentra en el texto'}
```

Por lo tanto un código de ejemplo podría ser algo así:

```
texto = input('Escribe un texto:')

diccionario = {0: 'Python no está en el texto', 1: 'Python si se encuentra en el texto'}

booleano = 'python' in texto  # En esta parte compruebas si 'python' está en el texto.

print(diccionario[booleano])  # Y devuelves el valor que hayas establecido en el diccionario
```